# Closest and quietest park/wooded area to NYC?

Tags: location-recording, quiet, foley, city

Hi All,

Maybe a strange question, but I am in need of a location for Foley, FS, Rustle etc. for a film shot in Yellowstone and I, of course, live in NYC.  I am hoping to get out this Saturday morning and am not sure of a decent place to go.  I was trying to see if I could make it work Foleying in the studio, but the main character is alone in the woods for a large portion of the film and most of those scenes was shot MOS, so placing myself in a "similar" environment would be great. I would be all for experimenting and trying out places or scouting locations beforehand, but alas, time is of the essence and I will most likely only have Saturday to work.  I was looking at a few parks on Staten Island which if early enough, might not have too many plane flyovers, or else driving up north towards Bear Mountain State Park was another option.  If anyone has any insight into this, it would be greatly appreciated.  I was in VT last weekend and brought my recorder along to, but of course, it poured almost the whole time so was a bust for recording (nice and relaxing though :-).  Thanks all.

Best,
Ryan

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember any places in NYC, but in New Jersey there were some really cool foresty places near norwood, wich were only a 45 minute bus ride from the grand central.

Comment: Also, Lawrence, in Long island is dead quiet on sundays.

Comment: Hi Felipe, Thanks very much, those are the kinds of places I am looking for, when I looked on the map I didn't really see any specific parks or wooded areas though, are there any specific areas?  And I have a car so travel isn't too bad, but the shorter the time the better. Thanks again. – Ryan 0 secs ago